# Field name doesn't exist error when viewing published workbook

Tags: field, tableau-api

I’m getting this error: “Field  ‘[tableName].fieldName’, which is included in a
join clause , does not exist. Unable to connect to the server "serverName".
Check that the server is running and that you have access privileges to the
requested database.Errors occurred while trying to load the workbook
"/views/reportName". The load was not able to complete successfully”.

I don’t have this problem in the desktop version but I get
this error in the server version. Apparently if I refresh several times the
report eventually loads. I started having this problem after modifying my sql
server table but the field names are same as the pre-modification. Any help
would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the workbook in Tableau Desktop and checking for any invalid dimensions, measures, parameters or calculated fields (they may have a red exclamation mark next to them). Once this check has been done, try republishing the workbook.

Failing that, send an email to support@tableausoftware.com, describing the issue in as much detail as possible, including a screenshot of the error and, if possible, a copy of the workbook and they will help resolve the issue.